# How to avoid "PHP injection"

Tags: php, security

I have this script

```
<?php $number = %value%; ?>
```

The %value% token will be replaced by a value on a DB input by a user.

My concern is that someone inputs something like:

```
1; echo phpinfo()
```

The result of the replace will be:

```
<?php $number = 1; echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

This is obviously a security risk.

Is there a function to escape php scripting characters or something I can use?

Thanks in advance.

### Context

This is a tool on a CMS I'm working on, usually tools generate HTML code added to some PHP file.

In this case this tool generates an HTML structure from an RSS channel. We ask the user to input the RSS URL and the number of feeds to display, we replace those values into the PHP script and use them to get the feeds and display them in a HTML structure.

like this:

```
<?php
  $url = "URL"; //comes from DB
  $number = N; //comes from DB
  $feeds = getFeeds($url, $number);
  ...
?>
```

Comment: How does the replacement happen?

Comment: It looks almost as if he's generating a PHP file dynamically based on user input. If so... Christ.

Comment: This is why Automattic doesn't allow custom WordPress themes in WordPress.com.

Comment: The process of replacing the %value% with the actual value store in the DB happens when creating a PHP file

Comment: there are very few, if any, valid reasons for PHP files to be created on the fly, especially with arbitrary user input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mechanics you described above are flawed. PHP just doesn't work that way. No user input will be executed (or to be more precise, interpreted by PHP) unless:

- You run it through an `eval()` call
- You save a combination of your code and user input as a PHP file and later execute it

What you should be worried is SQL injection which is an entierly different thing.

If you are referring to a scenario simillar to bullet #2, there is a good chance you are doing something quite wrong from the design perspective and you should rethink your approach.

Comment: I'm working on a CMS, so the process of replacing the %value% with the actual value store in the DB happens when creating a PHP file, so it will be executed

Comment: You shouldn't to such a thing. Just (and I cannot stress this enough) don't. Only if you can explain that you NEED it, and it isn't just done this way by the framework.

Comment: @Sebastian Perez, take a look at my updated answer. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by your code generation algo, but chances are there is a myriad of better, easier and more secure ways to do it. If you shed some more light on your goals I'm sure we can find one that suits your needs.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would use code generation for this. Why does the file have no access to the database? Why don't you use query strings (or rewritten, "pretty" URLs) to pass info to the file? htXp://www.domain.tld/scr/ipt/rss/N/index.php can be used to pass the number N to the script, among many different ways to pass info. Even an ini file with settings for different users is a way better choice than dynamic code generation.

Comment: You are right about the URL, I'll look into that. I agree with you all the design is flawed but it's the only way to do it by now for many reasons but I have to change that. Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: @Sebastian Perez: You are most welcome. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php might be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by code_burgar.. this design is totally flawed.  There should be no reason to build a server executed file on the fly.  You should pull your recordset from the db, loop through it and execute your getFeeds() function for each record.  Doing that would not execute any of the db provided data unless.. once again as cod_burgar says.. you use the eval() function.

Comment: well, the problem is that the value is in the CMS DB and the result PHP file is a user's file. In other words the result file can't access the CMS DB...

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to sanitize all user supplied input in any program. EG: If you are asking for a 5 digit number, before assigning data to a variable verify it is in fact an integer and make sure it is only 5 digits.

[Link to sanitizing PHP input](http://codeassembly.com/How-to-sanitize-your-php-input/)